# Cant show flag in react

Tags: html, reactjs

export default (imported as `Flag`) was not found in `react-flagpack` (module has no exports), any other method to display `Flag`?

```
      <button onClick={changeLanguage("en")}>
        <Flag code="GB" gradient="real-linear" size="s" hasDropShadow />
      </button>
```

Comment: did you run `npm install --save-dev react-flagback`?

Answer (score 1):

A [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Yummygum/react-flagpack/issues/45) is raised for this and it will get fixed.

In the meantime, you can switch back to version 1.0.0 and you won't have this error anymore.

```
npm i react-flagpack@1.0.0
```

Please note that the "GB" country code is not registered in this package.
For a full list country codes that you can use, [check this page](https://flagpack.xyz/docs/flag-index/).